# How to write a recursive method for returning all lines in a file containing a token String

Tags: java, recursion

My professor gave us an assignment to write a program that does a lot of things. One thing in specific this program does is go through a `.txt` file, and return all the instances of a word you specify and the line where they are located. For example, if this is the text file:

> This is a test.
>   Testing the word file.
>   This will be considered a test.

After running the method and searching for the word "test" you should receive back something like:

```
1: This is a test.       
3: This will be considered a test.
```

Now this is my problem. He wants us to do it in a recursive method, and I am not sure how to start up the method. I know for a recursive method you must call itself and reduce every time you call it, but, the parameter for this method is a word. Say I have:

```
String getTheWord (String word) {     
    if (word == 0){    //which still wouldn't compile, so I think I should use word == null     
        // something    
    }

    //something smart here      

    return getTheWord(word - 1); // which wouldn't compile
}
```

So how should I go about writing this? I think I must use a string for the parameter because how else will I know what the word I am looking for is? Or maybe I'm wrong, anything helps!

Comment: "homework" is probably not a great idea for the tag.

Comment: Start by explaining what `getTheWord()` does.

Comment: Also, what does it mean to compare a String to the int value 0? And how do you subtract 1 from a String? (These are the reasons that your code doesn't compile. However to figure out how to fix these problems, you need to answer my previous question.)

Comment: Jason - you will learn more if you **try** to solve this problem by yourself.  Come back when you have tried.  (What you have at the moment is complete nonsense from a Java perspective.  You can do better than that.)

Comment: The method `getTheWord()` should have two parameters - both of type String. The first param is the whole file content and the second param is the word you are looking for. Now in the body you cut the first word from the content of the file and call `getTheWord()` with the new content.

Comment: martini - ohhhh yes that is brilliant, I think that will do it

Comment: This is not a recursive problem.  Did the instructor say WHY he wants a recursive solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public String getTheWord(String textToSearch, String searchingFor,
  int currentLineNumber) {

    // Separate the text into lines.
    String[] lines = textToSearch.split('\n');

    // Get the first line of the (remaining) text.
    String firstLine = lines[0];

    // We're going to have some result from this method call: either
    // an empty string or a message indicating that we found the word.
    String resultFromThisLine = "";        

    // Now, look for the word.
    if (firstLine.contains(searchingFor)) {
        // We found it.
        resultFromThisLine = currentLineNumber + ": " + firstLine + "\n";
    }

    // Now we check to see if there are any lines left.
    if (lines.length == 1) {
        // This was the last line.
        return resultFromThisLine;
    } else {
        // There are more line(s).
        // Create a string with all lines but the first one.
        String remainingLines = "";
        for (int i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
            remainingLines += lines[i] + "\n";
        }


        // Here's the key part.
        // Take the result from this line, add it to the result from the
        // next line, and return *that*.

        return resultFromThisLine + getTheWord(remainingLines, searchingFor,
          currentLine + 1);

     }
}
```

Comment: Well this was totally much more than what I expected, but thanks very much for this. This totally makes the problem a lot easier to understand and know how to handle recursion when dealing with strings. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we should ask, why we should solve this problem using recursion. In the [Introduction to Computer Science - Java](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html) page we can find some characteristic, which describe recursive solution:

1. A simple base case which we have a solution for and a return value.
2. A way of getting our problem closer to the base case. I.e. a way to
   chop out part of the problem to get a somewhat simpler problem.
3. A recursive call which passes the simpler problem back into the
   method.

For me, your problem do not match to this characteristic at all.

But OK, you don't want to do it in this way - you have to.

First you should think about model, which can represent your problem. I have created simple `Line` class, which store line number and line.

```
class Line {

    private int number;
    private String text;

    public Line(int number, String text) {
        this.number = number;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number + " : " + text;
    }
}
```

Then, you should create solution where you using simple loop.

```
class LoopSearcher {

    public List<Line> findLines(String text, List<String> lines) {
        List<Line> matchLines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        int index = 0;
        for (String line : lines) {
            index++;
            if (line.contains(text)) {
                matchLines.add(new Line(index, line));
            }
        }
        return matchLines;
    }
}
```

You can test it in this way:

```
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream(new File(
        "D:/test.txt")));

List<Line> loopLines = new LoopSearcher().findLines("test", lines);

for (Line line : loopLines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Now, where we have loop solution, we can modify it into recursive solution:

```
class RecursiveSearcher {

    LinkedList<Line> matchLines = new LinkedList<Line>();

    public List<Line> findLines(String text, List<String> lines) {
        if (lines.isEmpty()) {
            return matchLines;
        }

        int number = lines.size() - 1;
        String line = lines.remove(number);
        if (line.contains(text)) {
            matchLines.addFirst(new Line(number + 1, line));
        }
        return findLines(text, lines);
    }
}
```

You can test it in this way:

```
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream(new File(
        "D:/test.txt")));

List<Line> recursiveLines = new RecursiveSearcher().findLines("test",
        lines);
for (Line line : recursiveLines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

As you see, I have create method with to parameters:

1. text - text which we want to find in each line
2. lines - list of all lines in the file. Of course, you can provide raw `String`, which can represent all file content.